# Openshift Online configure auto-idling

Tags: openshift

is there any way to configure the auto-idling time of my gears in Openshift Online let's say to 2 hours?

I've been googling but I only find mentions to this feature using Openshift Enterprise:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Enterprise/2/html/Deployment_Guide/Automated_Gear_Idling.html
and of course I cannot use it because Openshift Online does not provide root access to gears.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploying on OpenShift Online, you do not have control over your application idling. The [pricing page](https://www.openshift.com/pricing/plan-comparison.html) shows that free plans will automatically be idled after 24 hours, while the Bronze and Silver plans will never idle. It's done this way because of the way OpenShift Online handles multi-tenancy, if you were able to idle your application, it would also mean that you could idle your neighbors application.